# MATLAB is too slow calculation of Spearman's rank correlation for 9-element vectors

Tags: matlab, correlation

I need to calculate the Spearman's rank correlation (using `corr` function) for pairs of vectors with different lengths (for example 5-element vectors to 20-element vectors). The number of pairs is usually above 300 pairs for each length. I track the progress with `waitbar`. I have noticed that it takes unusually very long time for 9-element pair of vectors, where for other lengths (greater and smaller) it takes very short times. Since the formula is exactly the same, the problem must have originated in MATLAB function `corr`.

I wrote the following code to verify that the problem is with `corr` function and not other calculations that I have besides 'corr', where all of that calculations (including 'corr') take place inside some 2 or 3 'for' loops. The code repeats the timing 50 times to avoid accidental results.

The result is a [bar graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31kJC.jpg), confirming that it takes a long time for MATLAB to calculate Spearman's rank correlation for 9-element vectors. Since my calculations are not that heavy, this problem does not cause endless wait, it just increases the total time consumed for the whole process. Can someone tell me that what causes the problem and how to avoid it?

```
Times1 = zeros(20,50);

for i = 5:20
    for j = 1:50
        tic
        A = rand(i,2);
        [r,p] = corr(A(:,1),A(:,2),'type','Spearman');
        Times1(i,j) = toc;
    end
end

Times2 = mean(Times1,2);

bar(Times2);
xticks(1:25);
xlabel('number of elements in vectors');
ylabel('average time');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some investigation, I think I found the root of this very interesting problem. My tests have been conducted profiling every outer iteration using the built-in [Matlab profiler](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/profile.html), as follows:

```
res = cell(20,1);

for i = 5:20
    profile clear;
    profile on -history;

    for j = 1:50
        uni = rand(i,2);
        corr(uni(:,1),uni(:,2),'type','Spearman');
    end

    profile off;
    p = profile('info');

    res{i} = p.FunctionTable;
end
```

The produced output looks like this:

[image: Output]

The first thing I noticed is that the Spearman correlation for matrices with a number of rows less than or equal to `9` is computed in a different way than for matrices with `10` or more rows. For the former, the functions being internally called by the `corr` function are:

```
 Function                Number of Calls
----------------------- -----------------
'factorial'             100
'tiedrank>tr'           100
'tiedrank'              100
'corr>pvalSpearman'     50
'corr>rcumsum'          50
'perms>permsr'          50
'perms'                 50
'corr>spearmanExactSub' 50
'corr>corrPearson'      50
'corr>corrSpearman'     50
'corr'                  50
'parseArgs'             50
'parseArgs'             50
```

For the latter, the functions being internally called by the `corr` function are:

```
 Function                Number of Calls
----------------------- -----------------
'tiedrank>tr'           100
'tiedrank'              100
'corr>AS89'             50
'corr>pvalSpearman'     50
'corr>corrPearson'      50
'corr>corrSpearman'     50
'corr'                  50
'parseArgs'             50
'parseArgs'             50
```

Since the computation of the Spearman correlation for matrices with `10` or more rows seems to run smoothly and quickly and doesn't show any evidence of performance bottlenecks, I decided to avoid losing time investigating on this fact and I focused on the main concern: the small matrices.

I tried to understand the difference between the execution time of the whole process for a matrix with `5` rows and for one with `9` rows (the one notably showing the worst performance). This is the code I used:

```
res5 = res{5,1};
res5_tt = [res5.TotalTime];
res5_tt_perc = ((res5_tt ./ sum(res5_tt)) .* 100).';

res9_tt = [res{9,1}.TotalTime];
res9_tt_perc = ((res9_tt ./ sum(res9_tt)) .* 100).';

res_diff = res9_tt_perc - res5_tt_perc;
[~,res_diff_sort] = sort(res_diff,'desc');

tab = [cellstr(char(res5.FunctionName)) num2cell([res5_tt_perc res9_tt_perc res_diff])];
tab = tab(res_diff_sort,:);
tab = cell2table(tab,'VariableNames',{'Function' 'TT_M5' 'TT_M9' 'DIFF'});
```

And here is the result:

```
       Function                  TT_M5                TT_M9                  DIFF       
_______________________    _________________    __________________    __________________

'corr>spearmanExactSub'     7.14799963478685      16.2879721171023       9.1399724823154
'corr>pvalSpearman'         7.98185309750143      16.3043118970503      8.32245879954885
'perms>permsr'              3.47311716905926      8.73599255035966      5.26287538130039
'perms'                     4.58132952553723      8.77488502392486      4.19355549838763
'corr>corrSpearman'          15.629476293326       16.440893059217     0.811416765890929
'corr>rcumsum'             0.510550019981949    0.0152486312660671    -0.495301388715882
'factorial'                0.669357868472376    0.0163923929871943    -0.652965475485182
'parseArgs'                 1.54242684137027    0.0309456171268161     -1.51148122424345
'tiedrank>tr'               2.37642998160463     0.041010720272735      -2.3354192613319
'parseArgs'                  2.4288171135289    0.0486075856244615     -2.38020952790444
'corr>corrPearson'          2.49766877262937    0.0484657591710417     -2.44920301345833
'tiedrank'                  3.16762535118088    0.0543584195582888     -3.11326693162259
'corr'                      21.8214856092549      16.5664346332513     -5.25505097600355
```

Once the bottleneck was detected, I started analyzing the internal code (`open corr`) and I finally found the cause of the problem. Within the `spearmanExactSub`, this part of code is being executed (where `n` is the number of rows of the matrix):

```
n = arg1;
nfact = factorial(n);
Dperm = sum((repmat(1:n,nfact,1) - perms(1:n)).^2, 2);
```

A permutation is being computed on a vector whose values range from `1` to `n`. This is what comes into play increasing the computational complexity (and, obviously, the computational time) of the function. Other operations, like the subsequent `repmat` on `factorial(n)` of `1:n` and the ones below that point, contribute to worsen the situation. Now, long story short...

```
factorial(5) = 120
factorial(6) = 720
factorial(7) = 5040
factorial(8) = 40320
factorial(9) = 362880
```

can you see the reason why, between `5` and `9`, your bar graph shows an "exponentially" increasing computational time?

On a side note, there is nothing you can do to solve this problem, unless you find another implementation of the Spearman correlation that doesn't present the same bottleneck or you implement your own.